# Postgres cast Array to a Custom Type

Tags: arrays, postgresql, plpgsql, postgresql-9.5, postgresql-11

I have to cast a varchar array to a custom Type but it is failing.

Scenario

`CREATE TYPE foo AS (foo text[]);`

`SELECT ARRAY['TEST_ONE']::foo; -- fails with ERROR: cannot cast type text[] to foo`

I actually have to pass this type as an optional parameter to a function and hence I have to place its default value in the function parameters list. Like this

`create function foo_func(par1 foo DEFAULT ARRAY['TEST_ONE']::foo) ....`
but this doesn't work due to above mentioned issue...

Help will be much appreciated..

Comment: Why obfuscate such a simple thing as a text array with a custom type?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is hard to guess why someone would want to complicate his life with such a strange idea. Anyway, the type `foo` is a composite type with a single `text[]` element, so the literal should look like:

```
SELECT ROW(ARRAY['TEST_ONE'])::foo;
```

Maybe a [domain](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createdomain.html) would be more handy:

```
create domain foo as text[];
select array['test_one']::foo;
```

Comment: Thanks @Klin, this helps.. Its automated conversion of thousands of objects from Oracle. just picking the failed ones :)

Comment: I see. Did you think about a domain?